# treating nested tags differently with XQuery typeswitch

Tags: xml, xquery

I have a typeswitch function to convert parts of XML files into HTML, but I want to be able to differentiate between embedded and non-embedded occurrences of the same tags.  E.g., I would like

```
<nym>John</nym>
```

and

```
<def><nym>John</nym></def>
```

to be treated differently by the typeswitch.  I want something like:

```
declare 
function app:transform($nodes as node()*){
    for $node in $nodes
    return
    typeswitch ($node)
        case text () return
            $node
        case element (nym) return ()
        case element (def/nym) return
            <a href="view.html?canonical={$node}">{$node/text()}</a>
        default return ()
};
```

But this doesn't seem to be possible. Is there another way to create this sort of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers:

The way that involves **least upheaval to your code** is, as was suggested by joemfb, to insert a conditional into the rule for `element(nym)`:

```
declare function app:transform(
  $nodes as node()*
){
for $node in $nodes
return
typeswitch ($node)
    case text () return
        $node
    case element (nym) return
        if ($node/parent::def) then
            <a href="view.html?canonical={$node}"
            >{$node/text()}</a>
        else
            ()
    default return ()
```

};

The condition cannot go into the `case` clause of the typeswitch because typeswitch clauses take a sequence type, not a match pattern or location path:  `element()` is a legal location path, as is `element(nym)`, but not `element(def/nym)`.

The **simplest way** (or so it seems to me) is to abandon the typeswitch and use an if-then-else construct.  Keeping the notion of testing things against sequence types, as in the current code, you might write:

```
declare function app:transform2(
  $nodes as node()*
){
for $node in $nodes
return
    if ($node instance of text()) then 
        $node
    else if ($node instance of element(nym)
         and not($node/parent::* 
             instance of element(def))) then
        ()
    else if ($node instance of element(nym)
         and $node/parent::* 
         instance of element(def)) then
        <a href="view.html?canonical={$node}"
        >{$node/text()}</a>
    else ()
};
```

But for reasons I'm not sure I can put my fingers on, it feels more natural to me to write it this way:

```
declare function app:transform3(
  $nodes as node()*
){
for $node in $nodes
return
    if ($node/self::text()) then 
        $node
    else if ($node/self::nym
            [not(parent::def)]) then
        ()
    else if ($node/self::nym/parent::def) then
        <a href="view.html?canonical={$node}"
        >{$node/text()}</a>
    else ()
};
```

In my (shallow) testing, these all return the same result.

Comment: Thank: using `$node` instead of `tei:nym` in the antecedent of the conditional works.

This is not the only type of element I'm dealing with in the transform function, which is why I'm using typeswitch rather than something simpler (it's just that this is the only element type where I need this conditional behavior).

Answer (score 1):

You can't handle this directly in a `typeswitch` expression; you have to use a conditional in the return expression:

```
case element (nym) return
  if (nym[ancestor::def])
  then <a href="view.html?canonical={$node}">{$node/text()}</a>
  else ()
```

Comment: I swear, I got the above solution to work, and now it's no longer working, and I have no idea what changed.  If I cut & paste the above directly, then nothing happens because no namespace is indicated, and thus there is no case element (nym).  But if I edit the above to make nym and def all `tei:`, then I get this error message:

err:XPDY0002 Undefined context sequence for 'child::tei:nym[ancestor::tei:def]' [at line 131, column 21, source: /db/apps/dmnes/modules/app.xql]

Comment: Sorry, I left off the variable. Try `if ($node/tei:nym[ancestor::tei:def])`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a predicate filter in an xpath expression:

```
nym[parent::def]
nym[not(parent::def)]
```

This will test the immediate parent node. If you want to check all parents, use:

```
nym[ancestor::def]
nym[not(ancestor::def)]
```

Comment: like this?

`declare
function app:transform($nodes as node()*){
    for $node in $nodes
    return
    typeswitch ($node)
        case text () return
            $node
        case element (nym[not(parent::def)]) return ()
        case element (nym[parent::def)]) return
            <a href="view.html?canonical={$node}">{$node/text()}/a>`
        default return ()
};`

because that gives me a server error: "Syntax error within user defined function app:transform: unexpected token: [ [at line 130, column 34]"

[Sorry, I can't figure out how to format the code properly.]

Comment: Predicate filters should be working: http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-filter-expr. Maybe the syntax needs to be `element {nym[...]}` with curly braces?

Comment: Predicate filters in `[...]` work when I'm not in the context of typeswitch.  I tried with curly braces, and get a similar syntax error.

Comment: I assume `typeswitch` is only to be used for handling different types, and isn't equivalent to a generic `switch`. There's `switch` in XQuery v3.0 apparantly, but I guess you can also use a simple if/elseif/else construct instead.